# NDB: Query for unset properties?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I've had some data being gathered in production for a couple of days with, lets say, the following model:

```
class Tags(ndb.Model):
    dt_added = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    s_name   = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
```

Imagine I now add a new property to the model:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    is_valid = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    some_key = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

class Tags(ndb.Model):
    dt_added = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    name     = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    new_prop = ndb.StructuredProperty(Foo)
```

... and gather some more data with this new model.

So now I have a portion of data that has the property `new_prop` set, and another portion that does not have it set.

My question is: how to I query for the data with the new property `new_prop` NOT set?

I've tried:

```
query_tags = Tags.query(Tags.new_prop == None).fetch()
```

But does not seem to get the data without that property set... Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The Datastore distinguishes between an entity that does not possess a property and one that possesses the property with a null value (None).

> It is not possible to query for entities that are specifically lacking a given property. One alternative is to define a fixed (modeled) property with a default value of None, then filter for entities with None as the value of that property.